# Why is my python module not importing ON linux

Tags: python, linux, python-import

As you can see I have imported the modules correctly using pip install. I googled a bit why the module was not imported and I realized I have to add it to PATH. I did that too but now there is a new error something about a syntax error

```py
File "pygame/__init__.py",
self.reason = f"{exc_type.__name__}: {self.info}"
```

Is this because my chrome book can not run Pygame or is the problem something else?

Picture of my terminal with the error:

[image]

Comment: We need enough information to reproduce the problem **in the text of the question**; screenshots don't count towards meeting [mre] requirements. Copy-and-paste from the terminal _as text_ instead of taking screenshots.

Comment: (see also [Why not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run `python3`. to start python 3. Just running `python` starts python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

you have your installed packages in python 3.9 version while your python environment is 2.7, look for python3 executable and try with that version